# EWS intermittent "Unable to connect to the remote server" - Works 99% of the time

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have a c# app that exports data from the database to the user's Exchange Calendar, using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices (15.0.0.0). My app is DotNet 4.5.2 and I use Visual Studio 2013.

The app has been working fine for a year, and even now works 95% of the time. The app runs constantly on machine that I am logged into and monitor.  This is a low volume process, perhaps 50 items get exported per day at most.

Every couple of days, the program will give this error:
"The request failed. Unable to connect to the remote server"
when the app is attempting to create an EWS connection to the server.

It will do this for maybe 10-20 items. So I shut it down, run it again, and it works perfectly fine on all the records that failed before.

This is my first EWS app, but I've been programming 30+ years and do have somewhat little knowledge of internet based apps.

Any helpful information or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you kind people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internet often works, but should never be considered reliable. Anything using it should handle errors, and retry if desired. The classic approach is [Exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff). Its possible something nasty is going on, like your ISP swapped your IP address, or just intermittent failure. I don't know anything EWS specific, but there may also be sources of flaky issues there as well.